# Best practices for securing an embedded device

Tags: c, embedded

I'm currently developing an embedded controller, which will be connected to a potentially hostile environment. Since the Controller is quite limited (~50 MHz, ~16 KiB RAM), I do not have the luxury of an operating system which can help me with memory protection.

What is considered best practices for securing an embedded device? I know of techniques like stack guards, but since I'm not familiar with embedded development, I'm looking for some kind of guidance.

**Edit:** I'm using an ATSAMD21G18, which does not have an MMU. It's the same as used on many Arduinos. The controller will be conntected to a public bus (as in wiring, not the transportation method) thus I cannot assume anything about the behaviour of other bus members.

I am however not trying to protect IP, e.g. I'm not worried about somebody figuring out the contents of my controller. It's more about application security, e.g. how do I limit the harm done by somebody trying to take over my controller by exploiting e.g. buffer overruns.

Comment: Does your controller have an MMU ? If not then it's hard to see how you would implement stack guards or any other kind of memory protection ?

Comment: *"potentially hostile environment"* Hostile how? You haven't defined what threats you are trying to protect from.

Comment: What microcontroller are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure whether memory protection is the key in this case. Security issues come from outside .i.e. via input. No input - no security issue. (You cannot break into a house if it has neither doors nor windows.) To ban all comm. is probably not possible. Stackguards are good to detect buffer overruns. But careful design of communication (esp. input) to prevent e.g. buffer overruns should achieve this also. MMUs are helpful to prevent that one process accesses (in illegal manner) memory of another. For me, it's not clear how the "hostile environment" will be able to start such other process.

Answer (score 3):

Automotive MCU:s typically have a "copy cat" protection which blocks any form of debugger access - you can't read anything out of the MCU or debug it while this is active, you have to erase everything.

Check out MCU:s by silicon vendors with a lot to automative customers, such as NXP/Freescale or Renesas.

Comment: While your answer is valuable, I missed to express that I'm not concerned about protecting IP. It's more about resilience against attacks on the bus.

Comment: @ooxi Then your question is too broad, that's a big subject.

Comment: @Lundin I respectfully want to point out that if you have realized after answering that the question is in fact off topic, you should retract your answer. Close voting and also answering is not fair to other users.

Comment: This answer was written before OP made some clarifications and the question was closed. What's wrong with that?

Comment: You are right, my question is too broad. I just don't even know, what too look out for :-( Nevertheless I am very thankful for your answer, since it helps me protect against an attack vector which might be relevant for other projects!

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I cast the close vote after the question was changed and no longer on-topic. Read the edit history of the question before making such comments. The question is now also down-voted and will therefore get roomba-deleted together with this answer.